# Override jspDestroy() to close Session in Java EE

Tags: jsp, session, jakarta-ee

I want to remove my session when I close the window of my application. 
I'm trying to override jspDestroy() with session.setAttribute("user",null); but it doesn't work.

Comment: *I want to remove my session when I close the window of my application*. Why? It happens automatically when it get timed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the purpose of `jspDestroy()`. This method is the equivalent of the Servlet `destroy()` method. From the sample in the JSP 2.2 spec:

```
/** An example of a superclass for an HTTP JSP class */
abstract class ExampleHttpSuper implements HttpJspPage {

 /** What you are overriding */
 public void jspDestroy() {}

 final public void destroy() {
   jspDestroy();
 }

 final public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
 //remainder elided
```

This method will be invoked when the JSP is no longer servicing requests. It does not have a 1-1 relationship with user sessions.

Because the browser does not maintain an open connection with the server, terminating a session on browser close is a more involved topic. You can read about some approaches in the answers to [these similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20ending%20session%20on%20browser%20close).